# ASP.NET Receiving NullReferenceException on jQuery Bundle

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

**Issue**: I am receiving a *NullReferenceException* on @Scripts.Render("~bundles/jquery").

I deployed last night and tested, everything was fine. Woke up this morning, decided to check the site and noticed it. I haven't touched anything with the bundle either which is odd.

**THIS DOESN'T OCCUR LOCALLY**!!!!!!

**Code Snippet**

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
```

**BundleConfig**

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at https://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));
    }
```

**Things I've Tried:**

- Rebuild + Full Deploy
- Resets/Recycles
- Renaming Bundle w/ Hard Coded Version
  Any recommendations? Is this something with Minify?

**Edit #1**

[image]

**Edit #2**
I can confirm I see the JS File being loaded while accessing https://example.com/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js

**Edit #3** 
I tried to replace all my bundle references to pull from the Scripts & Content Folder and now I am getting some odd jQuery errors... **Note, I prefer to use bundling.**

```
<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
```

[image]

**Edit #4**
I have a TEMP solution by using latest CDN for Bootstrap, but I prefer using standard bundling.

Comment: You can try debug your bundles on your local like in production by putting this line in your  RegisterBundles:  BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true; I suspect your local is working because it does not actually bundle on debug

Comment: The real question is, why would it suddenly have trouble with bundling? It was in Production/Release working as expected. Are there any IIS configuration settings around bundling that could have caused it?

Comment: I just enabled Optimizations and now its occurring locally.

`System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.FunctionObject.SafeIsReferenced(Syste[..]`

Comment: Does the error stacktrace show any line number that ends in any layout view or resource file?

Comment: Its essentially the same thing in the OP. @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

Answer (score 0):

try to spell out the jquery version instead of putting {version}

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery.1.6.22.js"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

    // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
    // ready for production, use the build tool at https://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
              "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));

    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
              "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
              "~/Content/site.css"));
}
```

and make sure the js file is present in the compiled

Comment: I will give that a try and let you know!

Comment: I changed it, still receiving it.

Comment: - are the files on the server?

- if you access the url yoursite.com/bundles/jquery do you see the correct bundle?

Comment: Added a Screenshot

Comment: Additionally, I can confirm I see the jQuery file 

https://example.org/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js

Comment: This also doesn't occur locally. Not sure if that helps